# Calling local function with Jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a jQuery function as follows:

```
(function ($) {
    $.fn.autoSuggest = function (data, options) {
        function add_selected_item(data, num) {
            (function ($) {
                $.fn.autoSuggest = function (data, options) {
                    alert(data);
                }
            })(jQuery);
        }
    }
})(jQuery);
```

If I wanted to call the local `add_selected_item()` function from outside this function, how would I do it?

I've tried doing:

```
$.autoSuggest.add_selected_item(data, opt);
```

But am getting an `$.autoSuggest` is `undefined`.

Still learning the ropes with jQuery.  I am not sure exactly how this can be accomplished, if at all.

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe have the function outside and call it from inside?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best resource for authoring a properly structured jQuery plugin is the [Plugins/Authoring documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring). The part that is relevant to your post is the [Namespacing](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring#Namespacing) section.

To summarize, you are defining the function `add_selected_item` inside another function, which scopes it to within the `autoSuggest` function. This means that `add_selected_item` can only be invoked from inside the `autoSuggest`. This is why your previous attempts yield `undefined` when you try to access it.

Your solution is very close to the sample stub provided in the jQuery documentation. Have a look at the following, specifically the lines after "Method calling logic":

```
(function( $ ){

  var methods = {
    init : function( options ) { // THIS },
    show : function( ) { // IS   },
    hide : function( ) { // GOOD },
    update : function( content ) { // !!! }
  };

  $.fn.tooltip = function( method ) {

    // Method calling logic
    if ( methods[method] ) {
      return methods[ method ].apply( this, Array.prototype.slice.call( arguments, 1 ));
    } else if ( typeof method === 'object' || ! method ) {
      return methods.init.apply( this, arguments );
    } else {
      $.error( 'Method ' +  method + ' does not exist on jQuery.tooltip' );
    }    

  };

})( jQuery );
```

The usage of the "internal" functions inside this plugin are as follows:

```
$('div').tooltip('hide'); // calls the hide method
$('div').tooltip('update', 'This is the new tooltip content!'); // calls the update method
```

You can apply this same pattern to your plugin, like this:

```
(function($) {
    var methods = {
        init: function(data, options) {
            //put your init logic here.
        },
        add_selected_item: function(data, num) {
            //here's your other method
        }
    };

    $.fn.autoSuggest = function(method) {
        // Method calling logic
        if (methods[method]) {
            return methods[method].apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));
        } else if (typeof method === 'object' || !method) {
            return methods.init.apply(this, arguments);
        } else {
            $.error('Method ' + method + ' does not exist on jQuery.autoSuggest');
        }
    };
})(jQuery);
```

**Note:** I have not tested the above code, since I do not know the intentions of your plugin. Use this merely as a suggestion on how to restructure your code.

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

```
$.extend({
  autoSuggest: function(){
    ...
  }
});
```

or

```
$.fn.autoSuggest = function(){
  ...
};
```